# How to insert to Combobox into Tablewidget

Tags: c++, qt

```
QComboBox *combo1 = new QComboBox(this);

QStringList list;
list <<"TRUE"<<"FALSE";
combo1 = new QComboBox(this);
combo1->addItems(list);


for(int i=0;i<ui->tableWidget->rowCount();i++){

    if(a[i]==true){
        combo1->setCurrentIndex(0);
         ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,2,combo1);
    }
    else{
        combo1->setCurrentIndex(1);
         ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,2,combo1);
    }


}
```

my source code. last cell change combobox. but Except last cell, All cell not combobox, i want all cell change combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

```
combo1 = new QComboBox(ui->tableWidget);
```